# How disable bold button in TinyMCE only for headers?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-5

I want to control bold button in TinyMCE so that it becomes disabled for headers but could still work as usual for other text. Is it possible?

A great way to do that would be similar to how you can customize "[clear formatting](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-formatting/#exampleusingremove)" button where you can specify selectors, but this does not work for "bold" format.

```
tinymce.init({
  formats: {
    removeformat: [
      // Configures `clear formatting` to remove specified elements regardless of its attributes
      { selector: 'b,strong,em,i,font,u,strike', remove: 'all' },
    ]
  }
});
```

Code example: https://codepen.io/andreyprokhorov/pen/zYBbdVy

If I define bold style for a "span" then I cannot disable bold for headers (h1-h6). Besides that I want the "bold" button to look disabled when a header is chosen in the editor.

```
  formats: {
    bold: {  inline: 'span', classes: 'bold' }, //nothing disabled
    bold: {  selector: 'h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6', classes: '' },  //disables everything
    bold: [ {  inline: 'span', classes: 'bold' }, { selector: 'h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6', classes: '' }], //nothing disabled
  },
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it with "valid_children" [setting](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-filtering/#exampleusingvalid_children):

```
tinymce.init({
  valid_children : '-h1[strong|em],-h2[strong|em],-h3[strong|em],-h4[strong|em],-h5[strong|em]'
});
```

This rule disallows both bold and italic html-elements as children inside h1-h5. Unfortunately corresponding buttons are not disabled in the editor, but at least nothing happens when you click on them and they still work for other text.